# Do you still need to include "site" as a random effect when modeling matched data set?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, sas, propensity-scores, matching

I am working on a multicenter propensity matched cohort study. The primary outcome is binary while the secondary outcome is continuous. First I performed multiple imputation to address the missing data. I initially planned exact matching on the sites in addition to matching on other variables of interests but got very poor matches. Then I used variables that described the characteristics of the sites, which I compared with the site variable using c statistic and they had similar values. With this new variables and the other variables of interest I got a much better match. I then performed within imputation conditional logistic regression for the binary variable and pulled the results. For the secondary outcome I used negative binomial regression including the match ID in the class statement and as a repeated statement. Do I need to include 'site' as a random statement in the model? I don't know if this is possible in conditional logistic regression. What would be the best way to model this data after matching? For this study I used SAS for analysis.